# How to auto define a list of words for Anki deck?

Tags: dictionary, anki

I wish to create an Anki deck out of my *Google Translate* list, but not simply as English > Language, ENG > ENG with definitions and sentences.

I've got a list of words (like csv file) and now trying to find some kind of script to define each of this words and then import into the *Anki* deck.

What was tried:

- **AutoDefine** addon, was not working under the Android. This one uses http://www.dictionaryapi.com/# as API.
- http://www.easydefine.com/, no possibility to export. Need to parse this somehow.

Pretty sure there should be some existing solution before I start writing my own.